# How to include legacy module in Dojo AMD

Tags: dojo, amd

I'm trying to migrate an application from dojo 1.6 to version 1.9.1, and I've a legacy module that I didn't want to migrate yet (it's pretty complex and will take me some time to understand).  The Dojo docs indicate you can load legacy modules along with AMD modules, but when I try, I'm getting a "dojo.provide is not a function" when the loader tries to load the legacy module.

My script:

```
require([..., "agsjs/dijit/TOC","dojo/domReady!"], 
            function(..., TOC) {
    on(map,'layers-add-result',function(results){
        //Add Legend
        var toc = new TOC({
            map: map,
            layerInfos:legendLayers
        }, 'legendDiv');
        toc.startup();
    });
});
```

The first line of code of the module:

```
dojo.provide('agsjs.dijit.TOC');
```

Everything works until the loader tries to load the agsjs/dijit/TOC module, where I get a "dojo.provide is not a function" error.  How do I solve this without having to refactor the entire module to AMD?  Thanks

Comment: A search engine brought me here, so I'll leave here a link that was helpful to me: https://ilinkuo.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/dojo-amd-incorporating-third-party-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for legacy modules to load, you need to run the loader in legacy mode, which means you cannot set `async: true`. As long as you are running with `async: false` (the default), you will be able to load and use legacy modules from AMD modules, and vice-versa.

Comment: Not according to the tutorial. "One final feature exclusive to the Dojo loader is the ability to mix-and-match legacy Dojo modules with AMD-style modules. This makes it possible to slowly and methodically transition from a legacy codebase to an AMD codebase instead of needing to convert everything immediately. This works both when the loader is in sync mode and when it is in async mode" found http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modules/

Comment: The tutorial is not correct. Dojo Base (the old `dojo` object) is not loaded when in async mode, and typical `dojo.require` calls necessitate the use of synchronous loading (unless you are using the old XD mode). As the author of the tutorial I can attest to my wrongness in writing what was written there. At the time, the new loader was poorly documented and poorly understood.

Comment: That's a pretty good case for why I should accept your answer ;-).  Is there a way I can contribute to getting that corrected in the tutorial (not that I understand the loader at this point)?

Comment: The tutorial has been updated to be more accurate. As far as contributing, unfortunately the tutorials are the only documentation that is currently not in good source control (it is in an old Subversion repository). So there is no easy way to contribute to it. Dylan (dylan@dojotoolkit.org) can give you more information if you are interested in helping with the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A good point of AMD is that you don't have to use "dojo" and "dijit" global variables now. If you don't want change all those dojo.xxx calls in your old modules, you may try to wrap you old module in a

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojo", "dijit", 
        ...  
], function(declare, dojo, dijit) {

   return declare([/*your parent widgets*/], {

   //your old module content at here, maybe  you need make little modifications of your old module

   });

});
```

So that those dojo.xxx functions may still works.

This link may provide everything you need:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-17.html

Comment: That eliminated the error, but the code didn't actually work.

Comment: This is just save you time to convert whole legacy module into AMD. You still need take a look that document how to make your module works. For example, replace dojo.provide with declare.

Comment: See my modified version