# Dojo AMD and portlet-client-model

Tags: dojo, client-side, portlet, websphere-portal

I'm using Dojo 1.9.1 AMD with WebSphere 8 portlets and can't figure out how to continue to leverage the WebSphere mechanism for getting/setting user's portlet preferences.  Prior to moving from pre-AMD Dojo (1.6) to Dojo 1.9.1 AMD, I was including at the top of some JSP files these lines:

> ```
> <%@ taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/portal/v6.1/portlet-client-model"
>  prefix="portlet-client-model" %> <portlet:defineObjects/> 
>  <portlet-client-model:init>
>     <portlet-client-model:require module="ibm.portal.xml.*"/>
>     <portlet-client-model:require module="ibm.portal.portlet.*"/> 
>  </portlet-client-model:init>
> ```

which get converted/generated into these lines at run-time:

```
<script> if(typeof dojo=='undefined') {
  document.writeln("<scr"+"ipt src='/wps/portal_dojo/v1.4.3/dojo/dojo.js' ></scr"+"ipt>");
} </script>
<script>dojo.require('ibm.portal.xml.xpath'); dojo.require('ibm.portal.xml.xslt');</script>
<script>dojo.require('ibm.portal.portlet.portlet');</script>
<script>if(typeof(ibmPortalConfig) == "undefined") {ibmPortalConfig = {contentHandlerURI: "/wps/mycontenthandler/urs/!ut/p/digest!q8eCn6qc7fl2VjdmXXlayA/nm/oid:wps.portal.root"};} else if(!ibmPortalConfig["contentHandlerURI"]) {ibmPortalConfig["contentHandlerURI"] = "/wps/mycontenthandler/urs/!ut/p/digest!q8eCn6qc7fl2VjdmXXlayA/nm/oid:wps.portal.root";} </script><div id='com.ibm.wps.web2.portlet.root.Z7_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E530O2' style='display: none;'>/wps/mycontenthandler/urs/!ut/p/digest!q8eCn6qc7fl2VjdmXXlayA/pm/oid:--portletwindowid--@oid:Z6_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E530G4</div>
<div id='com.ibm.wps.web2.portlet.preferences.Z7_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E530O2' style='display: none;' pageid='Z6_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E530G4' configid='Z3_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E53085' editdefaultsid='Z5_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E530O6'
></div>
<div id='com.ibm.wps.web2.portlet.user.Z7_HHGGGIO0JGPN00AI72U5E530O2' style='display: none;'>/wps/mycontenthandler/urs/!ut/p/digest!q8eCn6qc7fl2VjdmXXlayA/um/secure/currentuser/profile?expandRefs=true</div>
```

which then allowed me to use javascript for getting and setting user portlet preferences.  When I try using this same technique with Dojo 1.9.1 AMD, the same code that is generated above causes a javascript error complaining that the "dojo.require" is not a function.

With the improved Dojo AMD, I no longer have any calls to "dojo.require" like I used to, so I haven't encountered this issue, but these WebSphere custom tags automatically generate "dojo.require" calls that are now failing.

Do I need to try to mix the old pre-AMD inclusion of dojo.js with the preferred AMD inclusion calls?   Has anyone encountered this issue yet?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: In dojo AMD you need to use just the `require()` function instead of `dojo.require`. so your WebSphere should generate `require(['ibm.portal.xml.xpath'])`. Now how the websphere generates the code of that I have no idea.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I've been looking for any updated WebSphere custom tag that would generate the AMD syntax but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: After more searching I found a similar question asked here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054350/how-to-include-legacy-module-in-dojo-amd with an answer that might work for me.  I'll change the async:true  to  async:false in the loader which should allow both old and new syntax to work.  Will report back soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you're using an old taglib. If I look at the URL I see that you're using a v6.1 taglib, which uses Dojo 1.4.3 and that is obviously outdated. Try to replace the taglib with:

```xml
<%@ taglib 
  uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/portal/v8.0/portlet-client-model"
  prefix="portlet-client-model" %>
```

I suppose that should generate some more appropriate code, compatible with the latest releases. You will probably have to update some libraries on your classpath as well.

---

Also, if you're using WebSphere Portal 8, then only Dojo 1.7 is supported officially, so make sure you're not using different versions here. WebSphere Portal 8.5 supports Dojo 1.9 (uses 1.9.3 to be exactly), but from your question it was not clear if you're using v8 or v8.5.

---

If you want to change the Dojo configuration and set `async: false`, that's possible, but you will have to set it **before** dojo.js is loaded. That means you will have to edit **theme.html** and the localized themes (for example **theme_en.html**) to add the following content above the `co:head` dynamic content spot:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
      async: false
    };
</script>
<link rel="dynamic-content" href="co:head">
```

Be careful though, if you set it, you might break something, I don't know if IBM has their own configuration that includes custom packages or not, but if they do and you're overriding that configuration, then it might lead to errors.

Comment: Appreciate your input.  I'll try that v8 taglib change now and report back soon.  I am using v8, not v8.5, and definitely prefer to leave async:true so hopefully can avoid setting it to false.

Comment: Tried it and unfortunately that v8.0 change to the taglib didn't make a difference.  Will keep looking for a solution.

Comment: It still generates code using Dojo 1.4.3? I think that it's worth opening a PMR for this. I mean, if you're using an 8.0 library, I suppose it should be compatible with WebSphere Portal 8.0, if that isn't the case, then IBM should probably look at it. However, are you sure you updated both the taglib JAR and the version in de JSP?

Comment: I didn't think to update the taglib jar.  Not sure yet where to find the updated jar, it it exists.  I'll start looking for it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with "You will probably have to update some libraries on your classpath as well."

Comment: This sounds promising.  I just searched my WebSphere 8.0 installation directory structures, WebSphere/PortalServer, WebSphere/AppServer, and WebSphere/wp_profile,  for any and all "*.tld" files and didn't find any portlet-client-model tld files.  I did find a bunch of v6 tld files under my theme module. They included: portal-v6-core.tld, portal-v6-dynamicui.tld, portal-v6-fmt.tld, portal-v6-logic.tld, portal-v6-navigation.tld, portal-v6-showtools.tld, portal-v6-skin.tld, portal-v6-theme-ext.tld, and portal-v601-web20.tld - but no portlet-client-model.tld.  Where can I find the v8 tlds?

Comment: Hmmmz, after looking at their docs it seems they never updated the taglib https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/dev/w2_clntprgmd_start.dita Maybe you will have to open a PMR for this issue.

Comment: I'll check that out.  Seems strange if it's truly not supported as I'm expecting.  Portal 8 has been out for awhile and I can't be the only developer that has run into this issue.  I must be overlooking something.  I'll open a PMR with IBM to hopefully get a definitive answer as to what I might be doing wrong and will report back.  Thanks.